# pass a javascript array to java array using json

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to pass a javascript array of items to a java server using JSON.
my server receives the following String:

```
[
    {"attr1":"SomeValue1","attr2":"SomeValue2"},
    {"attr1":"SomeValue3","attr2":"SomeValue4"}
]
```

I'm trying to use `JsonArray`, but am probably doing it wrong (I'm not adding my code here since it is probably just stupid).

Can anyone give me the proper way of creating an iterating over the values from my String?

Edit:
as requested, my stupid code:

```
    jsnobject = new JSONObject(items);  //items is the string described above
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("");
    if(jsonArray != null){
        for(int i=0 ; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("name = "+explrObject.get("fileName"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: *I'm not adding my code here since it is probably just stupid* we learn from making *stupid* things and convert them into *awesome*. Post your code and we will help you on the process.

Comment: You *have* to post your code here, however stupid you think it might appear, otherwise your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: What JSON library do you use? Certainly the `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` classes must come from somewhere.

Comment: @T-Bull http://json.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used JsonArray(previously I've used gson to go between json and Java), but looking at the [documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html)

It looks like you can create the JsonArray by passing in a correct json string into the constuctor. Then you should be able to iterate through it like a typical array.

```
JsonArray myArray = new JsonArray(jsonString);
int length = myArray.length();
for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
     myArray.get(i) 
//note this returns an object of type object, 
//use other get functions to get other types

}
```

Comment: Tried that, recived an error that a JSON string must start with a '{'

Comment: That is the answer, have no idea why it didnt work the first time - thanks

Comment: @user1432310 Be sure to use a JSON validation tool when running into problems. Javascript/JSON is painful without the proper tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSON.stringify(array)
```

without your code it is hard to see what you are wanting but this is how you convert js array to a JSON obj

Comment: The problem seems to be in Java side, not in JavaScript side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use J SON Serialize method you can pass the j son string ...